# Python Moving numbers in a list

Tags: python-3.x

How can I go about moving numbers in a given list?

For example (if I move 5):

```
example_list = [5,6,7,10,11,12]
```

output:

```
[6,7,5,10,11,12]
```

or if I move 12 output:

```
[5,12,6,7,10,11]
```

Is there a built-in Python function that can allow me to do that?

Comment: Please don't name your list `list` (or any variable, for that matter).

Comment: I'm not clear on how you are trying to move. When you move 5 it goes 2 spots to the right, and when you move 12 it goes to the front (1 spot to the right)? Can you clarify what "move" is supposed to do?

Comment: In the first one you meant output to be `[6,7,10,11,12,5]`?

Comment: I have edited the last example

Answer (score 5):

You can use the built in `pop` and `insert` functionality of the list. Here you specify the index of what element you want to pop and the index you where you want to insert it.

```
example_list = [5,6,7,10,11,12]
example_list.insert(2,example_list.pop(0))
```

> [6, 7, 5, 10, 11, 12]

and for the second example:

```
example_list.insert(0,example_list.pop(5))
```

> [12, 6, 7, 5, 10, 11]

This can also be done as a two step process.

```
element = example_list.pop(5)
example_list.insert(0,element)
```

---

As an aside, If you don't want to specify the index yourself you can use the `index` function to find the **first index** of the value.

```
element = example_list.pop(example_list.index(12))
example_list.insert(0,element)
```

Comment: how about if I dont just want to move the first number 2 to the right ... rather a specific number where ever it maybe in the list to the right

Comment: You can create an index relative to where the element was. i.e you can add the change to the old index when you are inserting it back into the list. list.insert(old_index+2,list.pop(old_index))

Comment: You may have to check if you are inserting after where the pop occurred as the pop reduces the list size by 1. This is not a problem if you are inserting before the pop but after the pop you should -1 as the list has temporarily decreased in size by one so all indexes after the pop and one smaller.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`collections.deque.rotate`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque.rotate):

```
>>> from collections import deque
>>> lis = [5,6,7,10,11,12]
>>> d = deque(lis)
>>> d.rotate(1)
>>> d
deque([12, 5, 6, 7, 10, 11])
>>> d.rotate(-2)
>>> d
deque([6, 7, 10, 11, 12, 5])
```

Help on `deque.rotate`:

```
rotate(...)
    Rotate the deque n steps to the right (default n=1).  If n is negative,
    rotates left.
```

---

To move 5 after 7:

```
>>> lis = [5,6,7,10,11,12]
>>> x = lis.pop(lis.index(5))
>>> lis.insert(lis.index(7)+1 , x)
>>> lis
[6, 7, 5, 10, 11, 12]
```

Note that `list.index` returns the index of first matched item, to get indexes of all matched items use `enumerate`.

Comment: okay I see that this code is good for moving the last elements ... but What if I also need to move elements in between ? like moving 5 after 7?

Comment: The second case doesn't match the first example output.

Comment: @user2891763 I've added another solution, may be that's what you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
def move(a_list, original_index, final_index):
    a_list.insert(final_index, a_list.pop(original_index))
    return a_list
```

Example:

```
>>> move([5,6,7,10,11,12], 0, 2)
[6,7,5,10,11,12]
```

If you wanted to move the first 5 in the list then you could do this:

```
>>> my_list = [5,6,7,10,11,12]
>>> move(my_list, my_list.index(5), 2)
[6,7,5,10,11,12]
```

Comment: I feel that this is a bit hard coded... what if I want to do this for other numbers as well ?

Comment: @user2891763: how is this hardcoded? He has a fully parametrized function

Comment: Nono - I completely misinterpreted local side-effects - your code is fine (+1)

Comment: @user2891763: if you absolutely want to move two to the right, then try this: `move(myList.index(myNum), myList.index(myNum)%len(myList))`

Comment: how about if I want to move a specific number two places to the right where ever that number may be in the list.

Comment: @user2891763 `move(myList.index(myNum), (myList.index(myNum)+2) % len(myList))`